# OpenCV - Gaussian Noise

Tags: opencv, normalization, gaussian, noise

here's my problem: I'm trying to create a simple program which adds Gaussian noise to an input image. The only constraints are that the input image is of type CV_64F (i.e. double) and the values are and must be kept normalized between 0 and 1.

The code I wrote is the following:

```
Mat my_noise;
my_ noise = Mat (input.size(), input.type());

randn(noise, 0, 5); //mean and variance

input += noise;
```

The above code doesn't work, the resulting image doesn't get displayed properly. I think that happens because it gets out of the 0,1 range. I modified the code like this:

```
Mat my_noise;
my_ noise = Mat (input.size(), input.type());

randn(noise, 0, 5); //mean and variance

input += noise;

normalize(input, input, 0.0, 1.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_64F);
```

but it still doesn't work. Again, the resulting image doesn't get displayed properly. Where is the problem? Remember: the input image is of type CV_64F and the values are normalized between 0 and 1 before adding noise and have to remain like also after the noise addition.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Gaussian noise can have arbitrary amplitude and can't be represented in [0, 1]. Renormalizing after adding the noise is a mistake, because just one large noise value could affect the whole image.

Probably what you need to do is *saturate* the image when adding the noise, values that would be greater than 1.0 are clamped to 1.0, and values that would be less than 0.0 are clamped to 0.0.

Something like

```
cv::Mat noise(input.size(), input.type());
cv::randn(noise, 0, 5); //mean and variance
input += noise;

cv::Mat  clamp_1 = cv::Mat::ones(input.size(), input.type());
cv::Mat  clamp_0 = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), input.type());
input = cv::max(input, clamp_0);
input = cv::min(input, clamp_1);
```

Also a noise variance of 5 is very large, it means that there is about a 92% chance that the `input + noise` will be outside the range [0, 1], assuming the input is uniformly distributed on [0, 1]. So your saturated image will be mostly black and white, with the input image having little effect on the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your code works, I only had to make one minor adjustment for color images. Instead of using clamp_1 and clamp_0, I changed that into:

    input = cv::max(input, 0);
    input = cv::min(input, 1);

as the minimum and maximum comparison is done per-channel when the second parameter is a scalar.

I'm not sure I got the first part of your explanation right, I'm sorry. If we try to limit the Gaussian (in the 0,1, for instance), we're no longer taking random numbers from a Gaussian distribution. On the other hand, why can't we normalize the result after adding noise?

Comment: Actually, by changing the variance to a much smaller value, if I use the second version of the code I wrote in my first post (the one with the normalization line), the image gets actually displayed, only that it appears to be darker. What's wrong?

Comment: @user3438376   consider  you have a pixel with just 4 pixels = [1 0.8 0.0 0.2]. Now suppose we add noise to one pixel in the image so it is [1 2 0.4 0.2]. Then when normalize the image you get [0.5 1 0.2 0.1] and the image is darker. Obviously this a contrived case it it is easier to make a case where the image gets lighter. What will happen will very much depend on what the image is  - a light image would tend to get darker, and a dark image would tend to get lighter .

Comment: I think I know what's wrong:

1) The standard deviation was too high in my first post, giving values outside 0,1.

2) The image becoming "darker" has to do with the normalization in itself apart from the noise. Here's what I did. I have an image normalized in 0,1 and here are some of its intensity values: 0.466111, 0.533333, 0.523333. If I apply another normalization in 0,1 to this image, here's how the intensities change: 0.830295, 1, 0.974755. They change, causing the picture to change! How does it pass from 0.466111 to 0.830295? The usual normalization formula doesn't work here. Any idea?

Comment: @user3438376 Without knowing the values for both lightest and darkest pixels it is not possible to say what will happen to three individual pixels.